# Nested DIV min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a nested DIV that needs to have a min-height of 100%.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8pj4366/2/)

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="nested">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main, #nested {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However, said inner div does not expand to a height of 100%.

I realize that this question has been asked a lot, but all solutions require setting a `height: 100%` on the parent container ('main' in this case). If I do this, the `nested` div will spill out of its parent when the content gets too large (press 'Add Block' in the fiddle a few times for reference). Is there any way to force the `min-height` *without* setting the parent height?

To clarify, I would like my content to not be cut off when it reaches the bounds of `#main`--`#main` should resize to hold the new content size instead. I would also like this to work < ie9 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want working for browsers ie9+ than you can use like something below**

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#nested{min-height: calc(100%-30);} // height of text
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current fiddle, the inner div will spill out because of the 'Main' text you have in your fiddle (if you set `#content` and `#main` to have a height of 100% each).  To avoid content spilling out, and keeping the 'Main' text if you want it, you can use `overflow: hidden` on `#main`, as well as setting the height of your divs to 100% - solving your problem that way.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8pj4366/20/)

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nested {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.